# R: how to make a qplot of side-by-side error bars for 2 different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(3.409091, 4.090909, 4.772728, 5.454546)
data <- structure(list(approach1 = c(1.02967633502518, 1.01580726843304, 1.04284139608584, 
                      1.04357840118423), approach2 = c(1.0173503641109, 1.00394712634612, 
                                                             1.02773624467658, 1.02863476832808)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                       -4L))

data.lower <- structure(list(approach1 = c(1.0115541354025, 0.993078788685045, 1.01974099190034, 
                      1.02080115708828), approach2 = c(0.997978808683001, 0.982131487818724, 
                                                             1.00420304483585, 1.00652657076137)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

data.upper <- structure(list(approach1 = c(1.05177371364311, 1.03851495380357, 1.06108886027293, 
                      1.06774282552092), approach2 = c(1.03841840431302, 1.0260370212124, 
                                                             1.04663363856828, 1.0525347857539)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

`data` contains the point estimates, and `data.lower`, `data.upper` contain the corresponding lower and upper limits of the error bars, respectively. Currently, I'm making 2 separate plots: one for approach1, and the other for approach2:

```
approach1_plot <- qplot(x, log(data$approach1), size=I(0.8)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=log(data.lower$approach1), ymax=log(data.upper$approach1)))

approach2_plot <- qplot(x, log(data$approach2), size=I(0.8)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=log(data.lower$approach2), ymax=log(data.upper$approach2)))
```

How can I make a single side-by-side plot of the error bars, color-coded by the approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be easier to work with this in ggplot2 if the data can be reshaped into a format where the variables you need are in columns and each observation is one row:

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_cols(
  data %>% mutate(x = x) %>% pivot_longer(-x, values_to = "data"),
  data.lower %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% select(lower = value),
  data.upper %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% select(upper = value)
) %>%

# The pipe "%>%" in the prior line feeds the above into the ggplot call below,
# but at this point it looks like this:
#      x name       data lower upper
#  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  3.41 approach1  1.03 1.01   1.05
#2  3.41 approach2  1.02 0.998  1.04
#3  4.09 approach1  1.02 0.993  1.04
#4  4.09 approach2  1.00 0.982  1.03

  ggplot(aes(x, color = name, ymin = log(lower), ymax = log(upper))) +
  geom_errorbar(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

To get the `data` as a point, you could use `geom_point` after defining the `y` term (by default the 2nd term in `aes()`) as `log(data)`:

```
ggplot(aes(x, log(data), color = name, ymin = log(lower), ymax = log(upper))) +
  geom_errorbar(position = "dodge") +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.61))
  # 0.61 found experimentally; I'm not familiar with the process for
  #   determining dodge parameter defaults
```

[image]

Comment: How can I also plot the data point in the middle of each error bar? i.e., the values in `data`